Is the pricing for GitHub larger runners reflected in billable time stats?
GitHub now features larger runners for GitHub actions, which provide more performance at higher costs per minute. For example, if a job runs on ubuntu-latest-4-cores instead of the standard runner ubuntu-latest, it has 4 vCPUs instead of 2 vCPUs, but also the price per minute doubles. My question is now regarding the billable time, which is displayed when I open a run of a github action: let us assume that my github action contains two jobs; one job in the action runs on ubuntu-latest for one minute, and another job runs on ubuntu-latest-4-cores for one minute, will the billable time be displayed as 3 minutes, taking the doubled price into account? Or will it be simply shown as 2 minutes (in which case the billable time is not proportional to the actual cost)?

After I did not receive any responses or comments here for a while, I re-posted the question on github discussions. Also no response yet, unfortunately: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/121200
